# clear all properties in object that dont exist in another object with lodash

Tags: javascript, oop, object, lodash

How can i clear all properties of `datacopy` that dont exist in `pk`

```
var datacopy={
  "RHID": "3",
  "NOME_REDZ": "4455",
  "EMAIL": "jose.infante@demo5555.pt",
  "EMAIL_PESSOAL": "jose.infante@demo5555.pt",
  "TELEMOVEL_1": "(351) 936 090 982",
  "DT_NASCIMENTO": "0000-00-00",
  "rhidwf": "3",
  "DT_RowId": "3"
}

var pk={
  "RHID": {
    "type": "numeric"
  },
  "SEQ"{
  "type": "numeric"
  }
}
```

I know the power of lodash and know this is possible.

Comment: in this case i want to clear all that are not RHID or SEQ   https://jsfiddle.net/zwpu70no/1/

Comment: how about a 'native' js solution?

Comment: "to clear" means deletion or setting empty string?

Comment: Delete is fine... robertklep solution is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can use [keys()](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) to get the properties from `pk` and then [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) properties from `datacopy` to persist key values using the `pk` property list.

```
var result = _.pick(datacopy, _.keys(pk));
```

```js
var datacopy = {
  "RHID": "3",
  "NOME_REDZ": "4455",
  "EMAIL": "jose.infante@demo5555.pt",
  "EMAIL_PESSOAL": "jose.infante@demo5555.pt",
  "TELEMOVEL_1": "(351) 936 090 982",
  "DT_NASCIMENTO": "0000-00-00",
  "rhidwf": "3",
  "DT_RowId": "3"
};

var pk = {
  "RHID": {
    "type": "numeric"
  },
  "SEQ": {
    "type": "numeric"
  }
};

var result = _.pick(datacopy, _.keys(pk));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Better solution than mine =D

Answer (score 1):

```
const _ = require('lodash');
...    
datacopy = _.omit(datacopy, _.difference(_.keys(datacopy), _.keys(pk)))
```

Comment: can you help me with tis one ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296915/add-propertie-to-object-if-propertie-exists-in-another-object-using-lodash

Answer (score 1):

"Pure" javascript one-line solution without any 'lodash'(as an alternative):

```
Object.keys(datacopy).forEach((k) => !pk[k] && delete datacopy[k]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(datacopy, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "RHID": "3"
}
```