# Add propertie to object if property exists in another object using lodash

Tags: javascript, oop, object, lodash

I have two objects and I need to add properties to one object based on match from properties of another:

```
var dependsOn= {
                qTableIdent: {
                    //External object key mapping( object key : external key)
                    'RHID': 'RHID',
                    'CD_AGREGADO': 'NOME'
                }
            },
var  tableCols= [
            {
                "targets": 1,
                "title": 'RHID',
                "label": 'RHID',
                "data": 'RHID',
                "name": 'RHID',
                "width": "5%",
                "filter": true,
                "defaultContent": "",
                "visible":false,
                "type": 'hidden',        //ADD this to properties 
                attr: {

                    'name': 'rhid'
                },
            },.....
        ]
```

I would like to add:

```
"visible":false,
"type": 'hidden',
```

to `tableCols` object where `data` property matches the property in `dependsOn`.

https://jsfiddle.net/zwpu70no/3/

Comment: to tableCols objects where data propertie exists as propertie in dependsOn

Comment: one more time ... how about native js solution?

Comment: could be...i am totally blocked

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `Object.keys` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```
var dependsOn = {
        qTableIdent: {'RHID': 'RHID', 'SEQ': 'NOME'},
        qTableDocs: {'RHID': 'RHID', 'DOC': 'DOC2'}
    },
    tableCols = [
        {
            "targets": 1,
            "title": 'RHID',
            "label": 'RHID',
            "data": 'RHID',
            "name": 'RHID',
            "width": "5%",
            "filter": true,
            "defaultContent": "",
            attr: {'name': 'rhid'}
        }
    ],
    newProps = {"visible": false, "type": 'hidden'},  // new properties to insert
    dataKeys = [];

Object.keys(dependsOn).forEach(function(k) {
    Object.keys(dependsOn[k]).forEach(function(key) {
        if (dataKeys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            dataKeys.push(key);
        }
    });
});
// dataKeys now contains unique keys list: ["RHID", "SEQ", "DOC"]

tableCols.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (dataKeys.indexOf(obj['data']) !== -1) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach((k) => obj[k] = this[k]);
    }
}, newProps);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tableCols, 0, 4));    

console.log(JSON.stringify(tableCols, 0 , 4));
```

The output example for a single object inside 'tableCols' array:

```
[
    {
        "targets": 1,
        "title": "RHID",
        "label": "RHID",
        "data": "RHID",
        "name": "RHID",
        "width": "5%",
        "filter": true,
        "defaultContent": "",
        "attr": {
            "name": "rhid"
        },
        "visible": false,
        "type": "hidden"
    }
]
```

Comment: the problem is that dependsOn is  may have more objects ...   kind of  `var newProps = {"visible": false, "type": 'hidden'};
            //var dataKeys = Object.keys(dependsOn['qTableIdent']);
            _.map(this.dependsOn,function (key) {

                _.map(this.tableCols,function (o) {
                    if (key.indexOf(obj['data']) !== -1) {
                        o.keys(this).forEach((k) => o[k] = key[k]);
                    }
                }, newProps);

            });
        }`

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos, show the extended `dependsOn` structure

Comment: `dependsOn: {
                qTableIdent: {
                   
                    'RHID': 'RHID',
                    'SEQ': 'NOME'
                },
                qTableDocs: {
                
                    'RHID': 'RHID',
                    'DOC': 'DOC2'
                }
            }`